# Delete push notification setting from phone

Tags: android, ios, actionscript-3, air

I was wondering if someone knows a way to completely remove the push notification from the iPhone/Androids settings?

I am building an AIR app in AS3 for mobile and on first launch the notification settings are stored in the phone settings but I need to remove this to be able to check some additional code that prompts the user to either accept/decline push notifications.

I am using Distriqt's extensions and everything is working well. I just need to remove the setting to check some other code block.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On iOS, the way to do this is to reset the phone's settings in the Settings app under "General" -> "Reset" -> "Reset All Settings". It will delete all your phone settings, though, so you should only do it on a test device.